# Campagnolo Ultrashift, Escape, Powershift Identification

Tags: campagnolo

Can anyone help identify if this generation of Campagnolo Chorus 10 speed alloy-only is ultrashift, escape, powershift, etc? I've done a bit of googling, but without much more knowledge on the parts, I can't be sure! I'm asking because I need to order new cabling for the group and want to make sure I get the right cables :)

They look exactly like these:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

They're second generation Ergopowers. I don't know the name for the mechanism, or even if there is one, but it seems similar to current UltraShift. For original spare part codes, look up Chorus 10S in [spare parts catalog](http://www.campagnolo.com/media/files/035_250_Catalogue_spare%20parts_tools_Campagnolo_2015_part_A.pdf). Looks like UltraShift cables have the same dimensions.

I have been using third party Campagnolo-compatible wires and Shimano outer cables with success, the original ones didn't seem to like low temperatures.